# ngAnimate (very) slow when using grid

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-animate, angular-material, angular-grid

I have 2 tabs:

```
1
```

has a grid with 1000 records

```
2
```

has a little piece of html code.

If i use ngAnimate while changing the tabs, it is very slow!(i mean, almost 10 seconds delay just for opaticy-transition).

I can understand that when 2->1 it might be slow, but when 1->2 it is much more slow!
What improvement can be done for this?

*ps: i tried this as grid "angulargrid, ui-grid and ng-grid"; as ui-framework "angular material and ui-bootstrap"*